# Recommended way to install a Python package with pip and no sudo privileges

Tags: python, installation, package, pip

I usually just use the command:

```
pip install --user <package>
```

but I've seen [here](http://rmjarvis.github.io/TreeCorr/html/overview.html) that this:

```
pip install <package> --install-option="--prefix=~"
```

can also be used to bypass the need for `sudo` privileges. About this command the site says:

> There is also a –user option with pip install, which installs into ~/.local. This is fine for the python module, but it puts the corr2 executable into ~/.local/bin, which is probably not in your path. The above command will instead install corr2 into ~/bin.

So apparently it does not behave the same way as the first command.

Is one way preferred over the other and if so why?

Comment: A lot of the system implementation of python-based.
If you change the rights of the owner, you can change the applications resources.
Write a script, and save the file as sudoers script.
Please install your packages by calling this script
@Gabriel

Comment: Why would you type the latter command if the former is a shortcut?

Comment: @cel are you saying that the latter is a shortcut of the former? Please read what I added to the question because it apparently is not.

Comment: Okay, per default it installs into different directories. If you look into the docs you will find that you can actually modify the folder to which `--user` installs. Basically this question seems to boil down to: "is it better to install into `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin`, which is highly subjective.

Comment: @cel that seems like an adequate answer. Would you mind expanding your comment in the for of an answer so i can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Python package installation guide is here:

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html

It recommends creating [Python virtual environments per project](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments) using `virtualenv` command (or `python3.4 -m venv`).

This is because if you are working with multiple Python projects they have different dependencies and having per project installation environments is the sane way to deal with this in Python.

Comment: Thanks Mikko, I'll check the virtual environments method to install the requirements.